# grid view and shared preference android error

Tags: android, gridview

I am facing few problems while using `grid view` and `shared preference in android.`

I am using `grid view` to get the image resource and pass the image `resource` to next `activity` to convert that to an image.

`Activity A` contains: code to convert resource image to image in `EditText`

`Activity B` contains: send image resource to `Activity A` (Select image from `Gridview`).

`Activity A` Code: code in this link: http://pastebin.com/AzUTEFWT

`Activity B` Code :code in this link: http://pastebin.com/cRp1vQan.

Please guide me in this issue.

I am able to diplay the `gridview` with images.

I get force close error when i select image in `gridview`

Comment: please post the logcat output with the exception of your force close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm, I think I have find the problem. It's here:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {  
              //         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
                                System.out.println("Emoji is:- " +arg2);
                                prefsEditor.putInt("key1", arg2);
                                prefsEditor.commit();
                              //  finish();

                dialog.hide();
                        }

                        private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String string,
                                        int modeWorldReadable) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return null;
                        }
              });
```

Your SharedPreference Object it's null, and you are treating to access to it.

```
 private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String string,
                                            int modeWorldReadable) {
                                    return null;
                            }
```

You need to return something, for example:

```
private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String string,
                                            int modeWorldReadable) {
                                    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); //You need to pass an Context object, don't forget it
                            }
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks David. Now i don get force close error. But i am unble to fetch the image i selected from grid view into EditText. Any ideas for that. please guide me.

Comment: Firstly. Why don't you use the startActivityForResults method instead of override the method Restart? [An example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities). Secondly, use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` instead of `this.getSharedPreferences()` on lines 55 and 56 (Activity A code). Tell me if it works